# UIButton.setTitle does not set UIButton.titleLabel.text to empty string

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

It is not a problem but I found out that `UIButton.setTitle` does not set `UIButton.titleLabel.text` to `""`. So if you want to set `UIButton.titleLabel.text` to `""` you should use `UIButton.titleLabel.text = ""` after `UIButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)`.

In playground it looks like:

```
import UIKit

let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("1", for: .normal)
print(button.titleLabel?.text ?? "no value")
//print 1
button.setTitle("2", for: .normal)
print(button.titleLabel?.text ?? "no value")
//print 2
button.setTitle("3", for: .normal)
print(button.titleLabel?.text ?? "no value")
//print 3
button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
print(button.titleLabel?.text ?? "no value")
//print 3 not ""
button.titleLabel?.text = ""
print(button.titleLabel?.text ?? "no value")
//print ""
```

But of course `button.titleLabel?.text = ""` works only after `button.setTitle("", for: .normal)`

```
button.setTitle("3", for: .normal)
button.titleLabel?.text = ""
print(button.titleLabel?.text ?? "no value")
//print 3
```

I do not understand why this works this way. Perhaps someone can explain why?

Answer (score 3):

You can see following apple description regarding button title set. See the red marked rectangle.

**Sender is instance of UIButton**

[image]

As per apple documentation:

> To set the actual text of the label, use setTitle(_:for:).
>
> button.titleLabel.text does not let you set the text.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, but this does not apply to an empty string.